# Android Dragging ListView and ContextMenu

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm still working with dragging listview (example from google https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q) - long click by listview item - goes dragging and I want to implement context menu on short click, but my changes do not seem towork. After short click on listview item goes dragging effect..

here is my code for activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Utils.changeTheme(this,getApplicationContext());
        Utils.setLang(this,getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        listView = (DynamicListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.text_view, productsArray);
        listView.setList(productsArray);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        registerForContextMenu(listView);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                view.showContextMenu();
            }
        });

    }
```

With simple listview, short click working without any problems...

Could anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution in this case is use popup menu instead of context menu.